# AirPlay2: Multi-room or speaker audio on MacOS

Tags: macos, audio, airplay

Is it possible to play music on multiple devices on MacOS via AirPlay, similar to the feature on [iOS 11 and above](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8222019)?

I've seen this working within Apple Music but have not found a way to do this via the control center or any other app on MacOS. As an alternative, I've tried putting all speakers in one room in Apple Home, but I'm not even able to select a specific room to play music in.

This seems like it should be a basic features, more so as it has been around on the iPhone for ages. Anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes, but not via the System Sound panel. As you know, you can use Apple Music to select multiple speakers in different rooms to play simultaneously.

[image: AirPlay in Apple Music]

If Apple Music is isn't your 'jam', you could also try a third party tool called SoundSource from Rogue Amoeba.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Pixelwiz. Indeed, I'm looking for a solution that also works outside of Apple Music. SoundSource is a paid software, right? Do you know of any free and ideally open source alternative?